# Kivy native spinbox number widget for insert number

Tags: python, html, kivy, qspinbox

I am making an app with Kivy and Python,is there a native way to create a field with a spinbox to select the number like in HTML for the tag input (type = "number") ?? I see there are checkboxes for Kivy but not this spinbox number; should I use a normal text input provided by Kivy and get the number from that?

Comment: For a spinbox in a desktop app scenario (the input field in wich you can type numbers on the keyboard, as well as incrementing the current values with on of the small arrows next to it), yeah, no native widget for that. So a custom widget  with a text input, and two buttons is the way to go.

I say it for anyone wondering the same thing, as you most probably resolved it by now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Spinner widget._

Comment: Care to develop a bit ?

Are you suggesting multiple spinners ? one for each digit ?
It could do the job, but that is quite ugly IMO.